# cdxgen does not detect the dependency

Tags: java, gradle, owasp, owasp-dependency-track

I want to get all the dependencies of the project, including build dependencies. For example, my project has a plugin:

```
plugins {
   id("org.jmailen.kotlinter") version "4.2.0"
}
```

I am trying to get bom.json with the following command:

```bash
GRADLE_DEPENDENCY_TASK="buildEnvironment"
cdxgen -t java -o bom.json
```

But the plugin is missing in the final bom.json.
I suspect that the utility doesn't know how to search for plugins in the gradle repository.
How can I get all dependencies, including build dependencies in bom format?

I also tried a special gradle plugin, but it doesn't know how to build dependencies at all.

```
plugins {
    id("org.cyclonedx.bom") version "1.8.2"
}
```